# How to set column to max of another column in MS Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, max

I have a table:

```
ID  ColA    ColB
1   100     0
2   103     0
3   105     0
4   108     0
5   109     0
```

I want to update ColB to the max of ColA (and then I will add ID to it to get 110,111,112,113,114 but I can't get ColB to be the max of ColA.

I have tried an `UPDATE Table1 SET ColB=(Select MAX(ColA) from Table1)` but I get `Operation must use an updateable query`.

I have also simply tried `UPDATE Table1 Set ColB=Max(ColA)` but then I get that `query does not include ColA as part of aggregate`.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far that aren't working, and what are they giving you?  Please provide a full set of information so that people can offer the correct help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DMax` to avoid the *Operation must use an updateable query* error:

```
update t
    set colb = Dmax("a", "t");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set colb = (select max(a) from t);
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried and that gives "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: @kstilts: when asking questions here, please add what you tried, and what the result was, so that people can more accurately understand what issue you are having.